# Do publisher ever automatically reject unread stories

Tags: style, publishing, rules

I understand that publishers get a lot of manuscripts to read, so I am wondering, are publishers known to reject a story from an unknown author the moment that realize he is using a so called experimental style?

For example, suppose that I have written a novel from a second person perspective, also suppose that a publisher has already accepted my synopsis and now wants the first few chapters, is it likely that they would automatically reject it?

Basically should I stick to the [rules of thumb](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/761/the-rules-of-writing) without question for my first few stories?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Publishers are always looking for a reason to reject submissions, because it is easy to reject (takes a few seconds), and much more work to accept.

I was once on an elevator with an editor and the elevator got stuck. The editor got out his phone and said "I can use this time to reject some submissions."

The trick is to know the editor and what they usually publish. If they publish experimental stuff, then send them experimental stuff. If they don't publish experimental stuff, don't send it to them.