# How can I write a novel?

Tags: novel

I don't have enough expertise, but, I have a very good plot in my mind. A psychological thriller kind of thing.

What is the easiest and affordable thing I can do to get it written?

Comment: Find  yourself a partner.

Comment: Hi anonymous! Welcome to Writers.SE :) I'm afraid this question is too broad to answer in the scope of a Q&A; writing a novel is a lot of work, of many different kinds. We can help with specific questions, but asking "how do I write a novel" is roughly equivalent to asking "how do I build a bridge" :P

Comment: (Unless I misunderstand you, and you're seeking a ghostwriter; somebody who you can hire to write the book for you? I don't _think_ that's what you're asking, but I might be mistaken.)

Comment: Just start writing. Seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beauty of writing is that you don't actually need to spend any money. You clearly have a computer because you posted this question, so you probably have  microsoft word. Use that to write it. For planning, either do it on the computer or get out some paper and plan.

Expertise will come with practice. The **only** way to write a good novel is practice. There are certain ['rules'](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/761/the-rules-of-writing) which you can follow, but they will only help you to a degree. Many things come with practice.

In honesty, I believe this question is pointless and the answer is obvious.To write a novel you have to write a novel. It's just like answering a maths problem. You've just got to answer it. It doesn't require a big investment, it just requires belief and dedication. You've got to persevere through doubts, and just write. That's the only answer. Just write.

If you don't want to write, or you're uninterested in consistently writing and finishing it, then I don't think you're the type of person to be writing a book.

**You've just got to write. There's infinite amounts of advise to be given, but all will be futile if you don't write.**

Comment: I'm not sure about Writers SE, but at ELU, it is frowned upon to write an answer to a question one believes is pointless, whose answer is obvious.  The thinking is, if the question is not well posed, and there are no answers, it will be automatically deleted after, I think, a month.

Comment: Well the guy might not have known, so just in case, I posted it. @aparente001

Comment: I got in a lot of trouble for taking that approach on ELU, and as my rep went up, some people there got very irritated with me for not following the norm.  I finally figured out what was going on somewhere around 7K rep.  // But I don't know what the norms are here.